# How to Use Exposed filter of Taxonomy term with depth in Taxonomy View

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views

I have a question which is similar to [How to use taxonomy terms(with depth) on a views exposed filter?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25171/how-to-use-taxonomy-termswith-depth-on-a-views-exposed-filter)

But problem in my case is that I am using views of type Taxonomy, here I don't get option in Filter "Taxonomy Term: Has content with depth".

I have my Taxonomy like :
-Country
  -State 1
    -City 1
    -City 2
    -City 3
  -State 2
    -City 4
    -City 5 
    -City 6

I want exposed filter which has 3 select boxes like : -Country- -State- -City-
- State and City boxes fillup by Ajax based on Country selected.

Then the view should be updated based on the selected filters.
i.e If I select State 1 then I should get results of all the Cities below it and even of State 1.

Please note that I am not using View of type content, My view type is Taxonomy.

Can anyone suggest me how should I get this working?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But problem in my case is that I am using views of type Taxonomy, here *I don't get option in Filter "Taxonomy Term: Has content with depth"*.

You can bring that option into scope if you add a **Relationship** of "Taxonomy term: Representative node" or "**Taxonomy term: Content using MY_VOCABULARY**" and general any relationship that will join the node (or other Entity) table with the taxonomy table.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have nodes show in your Views results, you need build a view of type node. If you want taxonomy terms to show up in your results, then you build a view of type taxonomy.

If you want to use the taxonomy term with depth filter, you'll need to rebuild your view as a node view.

For example, you have a real estate site with listings -- node type is "listing" and it was a location taxonomy term associated with it that says what city each listing is in. Build a node view and add a filter of taxonomy-term-with-depth with a depth of 10 so that selecting a state will also show listings for all the cities in that state.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I have used this Taxonomy "Country" as a field in other Taxonomy say "Listing". So I can't create view of type node, I have to create view of type "Taxonomy" only. and that does not offer taxonomy-term-with-depth option. Any other way I can get the depth of taxonomy in the view of other Taxonomy?